# Why is printing an instance of my object throwing it in a an infinite loop, and crashing with the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am making a Swift framework to handle large (256-bit) numbers so I created a struct called UInt256. I tried conforming it to FixedWidthInteger, UnsignedInteger, and BinaryInteger so that it can be used as a regular Swift integer type. My problem is printing it. Whenever I create a UInt256 with a certain value, it works just fine. When I try to print it, it calls the UInt256.init(integerLiteral:) for some reason, and that seems to throw it in an infinite loop, which ends up in the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

First, I went back to before I conformed it to all the integer protocols and it worked fine. I want to know why I can't successfully conform it without this error.

I have analyzed the thread when it crashes, and whenever it tries to print the object, it calls the UInt256.init(integerLiteral:) command with a value of 0.

One interesting thing I noticed was that the error has to do with arrays and array buffers. In that init function, I tried creating a useless array and it always crashes on the first line that includes an array initializer. Is this possibly because after the repeated loop, it runs out of space for the array buffer?

I tried adding a print statement in the suspect init function and tried printing the value passed to it. Sure enough, the test printed '0' like 100 times and then crashed.

Here is all code needed to paste it into a Playground:

```swift
import Foundation

/// Adds a character and a string
///
/// - Parameters:
///     - left: String
///     - right: Character
///
/// - Returns: The string with the appended character
public func +(left: String, right: Character) -> String {
    var newString = left
    newString.append(right)
    return newString
}

/// Adds a character to a given string, and assigns the new string to the original
///
/// - Parameters:
///     - left: inout String
///     - right: Character
///
/// - Returns: The string with the appended character
@discardableResult public func +=(left: inout String, right: Character) -> String {
    left = left + right
    return left
}

extension String {
    // MARK: Subscripts

    /// References the ith character of a string
    subscript (i: Int) -> Character {
        return self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: i)]
    }
}

/// The size of the big number
public let BN_SIZE = 4

/// Size of BN in Bytes
public let BN_SIZE_IN_BYTES = MemoryLayout<UInt64>.size * BN_SIZE

/// Size of a BN String
public let BN_STR_SIZE = (2 * BN_SIZE_IN_BYTES + 1)

/// An unsigned 256-bit integer, sometimes denoted as just 'BN', or a BigNumber
public struct UInt256: CustomDebugStringConvertible, FixedWidthInteger, UnsignedInteger {

    // MARK: Static properties

    /// It's just 0, expressed as a UInt256
    public static let zero = BigNumber()

    // MARK: Properties

    /// The BN as a hex string
    public var hexString: String {
        var string = ""
        let bnSizeCountdown = Array(1...BN_SIZE).reversed()
        for i in bnSizeCountdown {
            let uint64IndexCountdown = Array(1...16).reversed()
            for j in uint64IndexCountdown {
                string += toChar(self[i - 1] >> ((j - 1) * 4))
            }
        }

        return string
    }

    /// The hex representation of the BN, used for debugging
    public var debugDescription: String {
        return hexString
    }

    /// The array of UInt64's representing the BN. This is a fixed size of BN_SIZE
    public var array: [UInt64]

    // MARK: Initializers

    public init(integerLiteral value: UInt) {
        self.array = [UInt64](repeating: 0, count: BN_SIZE) // THIS is the line that gives me the error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeef3ffff8)
        self[0] = UInt64(value)
    }

    public init(_truncatingBits bits: UInt) {
        self.array = UInt256.from(int: bits).array
    }

    /// Creates a BN from an array of UInt64's
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - array: An array of UInt64's
    ///
    /// - Returns: Nil if the array size is incorrect, but otherwise returns the corresponding BN
    public init?(array: [UInt64]) {
        if array.count != BN_SIZE { return nil }
        self.array = array
    }

    /// Creates a BN from a hex string
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - hex: A hex string to be converted to BN
    ///
    /// - Returns: Returns nil if hex string is invalid
    public init?(hexString hex: String) {

        self.array = [UInt64](repeating: 0, count: BN_SIZE)

        for i in 0..<hex.count {
            if toNibble(hex[i]) == 16 { return nil }

            let reversedSequence = (1..<BN_SIZE).reversed()

            for j in reversedSequence {
                self[j] <<= 4
                self[j] |= (self[j - 1] >> 60) & 0x0f
            }

            self[0] <<= 4
            self[0] |= UInt64(toNibble(hex[i]) & 0x0f)
        }
    }

    /// Creates a BN of value 0
    public init() {
        self.array = [UInt64](repeating: 0, count: BN_SIZE)
    }

    // MARK: Static Functions

    /// Converts an Integer to a BigNumber
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - int: An UnsignedInteger to convert to a BigNumber
    ///
    /// - Returns: A BigNumber
    public static func from<T: UnsignedInteger>(int: T) -> BigNumber {
        var bn = BigNumber()
        bn[0] = UInt64(int)
        return bn
    }

    // MARK: Enumerations

    // MARK: Subscripts

    /// Gets or sets a value for the given index in the BN array representation
    public subscript(i: Int) -> UInt64 {
        get {
            return array[i]
        } set(newValue) {
            array[i] = newValue
        }
    }

    // MARK: Conformance Requirements

    public static var bitWidth: Int {
        return BN_SIZE_IN_BYTES * 8
    }

    public typealias Words = UInt64.Words

    public typealias IntegerLiteralType = UInt

    public func addingReportingOverflow(_ rhs: UInt256) -> (partialValue: UInt256, overflow: Bool) {
        return (self + rhs, (self > (self + rhs) ? false : true))
    }

    public func subtractingReportingOverflow(_ rhs: UInt256) -> (partialValue: UInt256, overflow: Bool) {
        return (self + rhs, (self < (self - rhs) ? false : true))
    }

    public func multipliedReportingOverflow(by rhs: UInt256) -> (partialValue: UInt256, overflow: Bool) {
        return (self * rhs, (self > (self * rhs) ? false : true))
    }

    public func dividedReportingOverflow(by rhs: UInt256) -> (partialValue: UInt256, overflow: Bool) {
        // don't trust this, I don't even know what this does
        return (self / rhs, (self > (self / rhs) ? false : true))
    }

    public func remainderReportingOverflow(dividingBy rhs: UInt256) -> (partialValue: UInt256, overflow: Bool) {
        // I don't know how this would result in an overflow, but whatever
        return (self % rhs, false)
    }

    public func multipliedFullWidth(by other: UInt256) -> (high: UInt256, low: UInt256) {
        // what does this even mean? Seriously, if someone else would like to write this part, that'd be great
        return (self, self)
    }

    public func dividingFullWidth(_ dividend: (high: UInt256, low: UInt256)) -> (quotient: UInt256, remainder: UInt256) {
        // what does this even mean? Seriously, if someone else would like to write this part, that'd be great
        return (self, self)
    }

    public var nonzeroBitCount: Int {
        var nonzeros: Int = 0
        for i in 0..<BN_SIZE {
            nonzeros += self[i].nonzeroBitCount
        }
        return nonzeros
    }

    public var leadingZeroBitCount: Int {
        var leadingZeros: Int = self[3].leadingZeroBitCount
        for i in (0..<(BN_SIZE-1)).reversed() {
            if self[i+1].nonzeroBitCount > 0 {
                break
            }
            leadingZeros += self[i].leadingZeroBitCount
        }
        return leadingZeros
    }

    public var byteSwapped: UInt256 {
        let reversedArray = self.array.reversed()
        return UInt256(array: reversedArray.map { $0.byteSwapped })!
    }



    public var words: UInt64.Words {
        // I have no idea what this variable is supposed to be.
        // someone else please do this
        return UInt64.Words(8)
    }

    public var trailingZeroBitCount: Int {
        // I couldn't be bothered to write this right now.
        // I'm in the car after a long day and I am tired
        // I just want this project to build so I can say I had a good day and go to sleep
        return 0
    }

    // MARK: Private Methods

    /// Converts an ascii hex character to a nibble
    func toNibble(_ char: Character) -> UInt8 {
        let n = UInt64(char.asciiValue!)
        return  ((n >= 0x30) && (n <= 0x39)) ? UInt8(n - 0x30):
            ((n >= 0x41) && (n <= 0x46)) ? UInt8(n - 0x37):
            ((n >= 0x61) && (n <= 0x66)) ? UInt8(n - 0x57):
        0x10
    }

    /// Converts a nibble to a hex character
    func toChar(_ nibble: UInt64) -> Character {
        var c: Character
        let n = 0x0f&nibble

        if 0 <= n && n < 10 {
            c = String(n)[0]
        } else {
            switch n {
            case 10:
                c = "A"
            case 11:
                c = "B"
            case 12:
                c = "C"
            case 13:
                c = "D"
            case 14:
                c = "E"
            case 15:
                c = "F"
            case 255:
                c = "F"
            case 16:
                c = "0"
            default:
                c = "X"
            }
        }

        return c
    }

    // MARK: Comparisons

    /// Checks if two BNs are equal
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - a: A BN
    ///     - b: Another BN
    ///
    /// - Returns: True if they are equal, false if not
    public static func == (a: BN, b: BN) -> Bool {
        for i in 0..<BN_SIZE {
            if a[i] != b[i] {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    /// Checks if two BNs are unequal
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - a: A BN
    ///     - b: Another BN
    ///
    /// - Returns: True if they are unequal, false if not
    public static func != (a: BN, b: BN) -> Bool {
        return !(a == b)
    }

    /// Checks if a BN is smaller than another BN
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - a: The number that is checked to be smaller
    ///     - b: The number that is checked to be larger
    ///
    /// - Returns: True if a < b, false if otherwise
    public static func < (a: BN, b: BN) -> Bool {
        if a == b { return false }
        for i in 0..<BN_SIZE {
            if a[3-i] > b[3-i] { return false }
        }
        return true
    }

    /// Checks if a BN is larger than another BN
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - a: The number that is checked to be larger
    ///     - b: The number that is checked to be smaller
    ///
    /// - Returns: True if a < b, false if otherwise
    public static func > (a: BN, b: BN) -> Bool {
        if a == b { return false }
        for i in 0..<BN_SIZE {
            if a[3-i] < b[3-i] { return false }
        }
        return true
    }

    /// Greater than OR equal to
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - a: A BN
    ///     - b: Another BN
    ///
    /// - Returns: TRUE if a >= b, false if otherwise
    public static func >= (a: BN, b: BN) -> Bool {
        return a == b || a > b
    }

    /// Less than OR equal to
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - a: A BN
    ///     - b: Another BN
    ///
    /// - Returns: TRUE if a <= b, false if otherwise
    public static func <= (a: BN, b: BN) -> Bool {
        return a == b || a < b
    }

    // MARK: Arithemetic

    /// Adds two BigNumbers
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - a: Left BN
    ///     - b: Right BN
    ///
    /// - Returns: Sum of left BN and right BN
    public static func + (a: BigNumber, b: BigNumber) -> BigNumber {

        var r = BigNumber()
        var carry_out: UInt64 = 0
        var carry_in: UInt64 = 0

        for i in 0..<BN_SIZE {
            r[i] = a[i] &+ b[i]
            if (r[i] < a[i]) {
                carry_out = 1
            }
            if (carry_in != 0) {
                r[i] &+= 1
                if ( 0 == r[i]) {
                    carry_out = 1
                }
            }
            carry_in = carry_out
            carry_out = 0
        }

        return r
    }

    /// Subtracts BigNumber b from BigNumber a
    ///
    /// If the subtraction will result in a negative number, there will be an overflow error
    ///
    /// This uses Two's Complement subtraction
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - a: Left BigNumber
    ///     - b: Right BigNumber
    ///
    /// - Returns: Difference of parameters
    public static func - (a: BigNumber, b: BigNumber) -> BigNumber {

        // First, calculate two's complement of B

        var b_t = b

        for i in 0..<b_t.array.count {
            b_t.array[i] = ~b_t.array[i]
        }

        b_t = b_t + UInt256.from(int: UInt(1))

        return a + b_t
    }

    /// Multiplies two BNs
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - a: A BN Factor
    ///     - b: Another BN Factor
    ///
    /// - Returns: The product
    public static func * (a: BigNumber, b: BigNumber) -> BigNumber {
        var p = BN()

        let multiplier = a < b  ? a : b
        let adder      = a >= b ? a : b

        var index = multiplier
        let zero  = BN()
        while index != zero {
            p = p + adder
            index = index - UInt256.from(int: UInt(1))
        }

        return p
    }

    /// Divides BN a by BN b, and returns the quotient
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - a: Dividend
    ///     - b: Divisor
    ///
    /// - Returns: The quotient
    public static func / (a: BN, b: BN) -> BN {
        if b == BN.zero { fatalError("Dude you can't divide by zero in OUR universe") }
        var q = BN.zero
        var dividend = a
        while (dividend >= b) {
            q = q + UInt256.from(int: UInt(1))
            dividend = dividend - b
        }
        return q
    }

    /// Modulo operator
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - a: Dividend
    ///     - b: Divisor
    ///
    /// - Returns: The remainder as a BN after division
    public static func % (a: BN, b: BN) -> BN {
        if b == BN.zero { fatalError("Dividing by zero is not possible, sorry!") }
        var dividend = a
        while (dividend >= b) {
            dividend = dividend - b
        }
        return dividend
    }

    // MARK: Bitwise operators

    /// Bitwise AND operator
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - a: A UInt256
    ///     - b: Another UInt256
    ///
    /// - Returns: The bitwise AND of the two values
    public static func & (a: UInt256, b: UInt256) -> UInt256 {
        var ANDarray: [UInt64] = a.array
        for i in 0..<ANDarray.count {
            ANDarray[i] &= b[i]
        }
        return UInt256(array: ANDarray)!
    }

    /// Bitwise OR operator
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - a: A UInt256
    ///     - b: Another UInt256
    ///
    /// - Returns: The bitwise OR of the two values
    public static func | (a: UInt256, b: UInt256) -> UInt256 {
        var ANDarray: [UInt64] = a.array
        for i in 0..<ANDarray.count {
            ANDarray[i] |= b[i]
        }
        return UInt256(array: ANDarray)!
    }

    /// Bitwise XOR operator
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - a: A UInt256
    ///     - b: Another UInt256
    ///
    /// - Returns: The bitwise XOR of the two values
    public static func ^ (a: UInt256, b: UInt256) -> UInt256 {
        var ANDarray: [UInt64] = a.array
        for i in 0..<ANDarray.count {
            ANDarray[i] ^= b[i]
        }
        return UInt256(array: ANDarray)!
    }

    // MARK: Assignment operators

    public static func *= (lhs: inout UInt256, rhs: UInt256) {
        lhs = lhs * rhs
    }

    public static func += (lhs: inout UInt256, rhs: UInt256) {
        lhs = lhs + rhs
    }

    public static func -= (lhs: inout UInt256, rhs: UInt256) {
        lhs = lhs - rhs
    }

    public static func /= (lhs: inout UInt256, rhs: UInt256) {
        lhs = lhs / rhs
    }

    public static func %= (lhs: inout UInt256, rhs: UInt256) {
        lhs = lhs % rhs
    }

    public static func &= (lhs: inout UInt256, rhs: UInt256) {
        lhs = lhs & rhs
    }

    public static func |= (lhs: inout UInt256, rhs: UInt256) {
        lhs = lhs | rhs
    }

    public static func ^= (lhs: inout UInt256, rhs: UInt256) {
        lhs = lhs ^ rhs
    }

    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        for uint64 in array {
            hasher.combine(uint64)
        }
    }

}

/// For convenience, a UInt256 can be known as a BN
public typealias BN = UInt256

/// For convenience, a UInt256 can be known as a BigNumber
public typealias BigNumber = UInt256
```

Here is the test code:

```swift
let a: UInt256 = 42

print(a)
```

Any additional code you want to see can be found at [the GitHub page](https://github.com/SylvanM/BigNumber)

The expected result from the tests should be a "2A" (42 in hex) proceeded by a bunch of 0's. Instead, it just crashes.

This error has been giving me a headache because I have absolutely no idea where to begin. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is `BN_SIZE`? What is `from(int:)`? Please post just enough code that someone can copy and paste into a playground and reproduce your issue.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry about that! I added the code. BN_SIZE is the amount of UInt64's in a UInt256 (so 4) and from(int:) is just a function that creates a UInt256 from an unsigned integer. Sorry I didn't include those earlier.

Comment: Again, post just the right amount of code such that it can be copied and pasted into a playground and tested as-is. Your code, as posted, has lots of errors.

Comment: @rmaddy All needed code is in there. I pasted all that into a Playground on my end as well to make sure that's all the code that's needed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Last time. Post just enough code. There is no way that much code is needed to demonstrate the issue. Make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: @rmaddy You said there were a lot of errors when you put it in a Playground. A lot of those errors were there because when I left out a lot of code, it no longer conformed to the protocols I was trying to conform it to. Removing all that code would certainly make the code simpler, but would it would not work in a Playground as you wanted. I'm not quite sure how else to post the code.

Answer (score 1):

Change `print(a)` to `debugPrint(a)`. You have a coherent implementation of `debugDescription` so calling `debugPrint` will work.

Comment: Avoid `print` until you figure out where the recursion is coming from.

Comment: I’ll try that, but why is it that print(a) won’t work?

Comment: I don't know that. You've hooked things up in some way that causes recursion. The point is that you have implemented `debugDescription` but you are not calling it. Call it. You have not told your types how to respond to `print` but you have told them how to respond to `debugPrint`. So do that.

Comment: Also I would like to point out that you are reinventing the wheel, as big-number libraries for Swift already exist.

Comment: Duly noted. Also I’m more making the big number library for experience so I can learn more.